# Code written in VS code in the same tag breaks in multiple lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, formatter

[image]

When I write a  tag in VS Code, it automatically breaks into multiple lines. I'm using prettier as code formatter.  I searched for the solution and found that setting Prettier: Print Width  to 30/0 resolves this issue. However, as you can see in the image, it doesn't work. Code in same tag should appear in same line.

How can I prevent line breaks within a tag?

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you have print width set to 300... I'd recommend changing it to around 100 (it can make code easier to read if it is spread over a few lines like that, especially as the file size grows.), however if you are adamant in having it at 300 follow the steps below.

First of all ensure that you have Prettier installed, either locally in the project by running:

`npm install -D prettier`

or globally

`npm install -G prettier`

> Swap out `npm` for `yarn` or `pnpm` if you prefer a different package manager.

Next make sure you are actually formatting the document after setting the print width: either open the command palette <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> for Windows or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> for macOS and then search for `Format Document` or by applying the `Format on Save` options, to do so open `settings.json` by searching for `Open User Settings (json)` in the command palette. and then adding the following snippet within the json object.

```json
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

Comment: and this answers the question... how?

Comment: I was trying to gauge whether the user's editor is actually formatting the code.